# Salida por pantalla en misma linia con un input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode, pycharm

Como hago para que que se imprima en la misma linea algo, **después de utilizar un `<input>`**:

```
var = str(input("primera linea ", end= "")
print(">>>>")
```

El inconveniente es que input solo coge un argumento solo, no es como el `<print>`, quiero que se imprima de la siguiente manera:

```
primera linea Algo escrito por el usuario>>>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta

Comment: yo pido al usuario que me escriba algo (<input>) y luego cuando haga un print en ves de que se imprima en la siguiente linia, quiero que salga en la misma que donde el usuario escobio.

Comment: creo que con el módulo `os` podrías hacer lo que quieres, aunque de forma bastante extraña

Comment: Claro que si el usuario presiona Enter, Python debe mostrar el Enter, como cualquier otro caracter.